# Running a function at random intervals C#

Tags: c#, timer, system.timers.timer

I have this function below that I call on my constructor:

```
 public void IntervalSC()
 {
     Random rnd = new Random();
     double interval = rnd.Next(2000, 6000);
     var SCTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
     SCTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(dashboardController.Screenshot);
     SCTimer.Interval = interval;
     SCTimer.Enabled = true;
 }
```

I want the interval to run `dashboardController.Screenshot` between 2000 and 6000 but after the random number is generated, it doesn't change and keeps running the `Screenshot` function at a fixed interval generated by `rnd`. I understand that it's because `IntervalSC()` is ran once so the random number for the interval is generated only once too. So I'm looking for suggestions on how to make this work, running `dashboardController.Screenshot` at random intervals. Thank you.

Comment: 1) Make `SCTimer` and `rnd` class-level fields. 2) Add a second handler to `SCTimer.Elapsed`. 3) In the second handler's implementation, change the value of `SCTimer.Interval` to a new random value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could edit the timer inside `dashboardController.Screenshot` but I feel it's cleaner to add another handler to do that. For example:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

void Main()
{
    double interval = rnd.Next(2000, 6000);
    var SCTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    SCTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(dashboardController.Screenshot);
    SCTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ChangeTimerInterval);
    SCTimer.Interval = interval;
    SCTimer.Enabled = true;
}

public void ChangeTimerInterval(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var timer = source as System.Timers.Timer;
    
    timer.Interval = rnd.Next(2000, 6000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this.

- It uses the *async and await pattern*
- Captures any *syncronization context*
- It will run well with an async workload and the UI
- It is also cancellable

**Example**

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

public async Task Generate(Func<Task> callback, CancellationToken cancellation)
{
   try
   {
      while (!cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
         try
         {
            await callback();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             // log your errors here
         }
  
         await Task.Delay(rnd.Next(2000, 6000), cancellation);
      }
   }
   catch (OperationCanceledException) {}
}
```

**Usage**

```
_ = Generate(someMethodAsync, YourCancellationToken);
```